# How to allow scaling with uniform aspect ratio in (Py)Qt?

Tags: python, user-interface, qt, pyqt

If you have a QImage wrapped inside a QLabel, is it possible to scale it up or down when you resize the window and maintain the aspect ratio (so the image doesn't become distorted)? I figured out that it can scale using setScaledContents(), and you can set a minimum and maximum size, but the image still loses its aspect.

It would be great if this could be explained using Python (since I don't know c++), but I'll take what I can get. :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm showing this as C++, which is what the documentation I'm looking at is in.  It shouldn't be too difficult to convert to python.

You need to create a custom derivative of `QLayoutItem`, which overrides `bool hasHeightForWidth()` and `int heightForWidth( int width)` to preserve the aspect ratio somehow.  You could either pass the image in and query it, or you could just set the ratio directly.  You'll also need to make sure the `widget()` function returns a pointer to the proper label.

Once that is done, you can add a layout item to a layout in the same manner you would a widget.  So when your label gets added, change it to use your custom layout item class.

I haven't actually tested any of this, so it is a theoretical solution at this point.  I don't know of any way to do this solution through designer, if that was desired.

Comment: Hi thanks! This looks like it'll probably work, but I think I might just let it slide for the time being. I think it's beyond the scope of my Qt capabilities and my deadline is coming up sooner than I'd prefer. I'll try to revisit this after I get closer to finishing and get back with you!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image to a `QPixmap` (use `QPixmap.fromImage(img)`) and then, you can use [`scaledToHeight()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qpixmap.html#scaledToHeight).

Comment: Thanks Aaron! That doesn't do quite what I'm looking for. That statically scales the image (QPixmap) upon creation, but it doesn't scale when I resize the window. Any other ideas?

Comment: In that case, don't scale but put a QLabel into the window and call `setPixmap()` on it. Qt will then scale the image along with the label and it *should* preserve the aspect.

Comment: Hi! Thanks again. Setting a QPixmap didn't scale, but it is good to know that I can set it with a Pixmap directly rather than setting a QImage first.